# Solving unknown exponent in 27^k ≡ 2 mod 2021

Tags: totient-function

27^k ≡ 2 mod 2021
How would I solve this using Totients. Been racking my brain for like 2 hours and cannot make any progress what so ever

Comment: Factor $2021$ as the product of two small primes.  Solve the problem for each prime, then use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).