# Find $k$: $27^k\equiv 2\mod 2021$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

By using these:
$$2^{11}=2048\equiv 27\mod 2021$$
$$2021=43\cdot 47$$

I should find integer $k$

$$27^k\equiv 2\mod2021$$

Well,
I can only come up with something like this:
$$a^{42}\equiv 1\mod 43$$
$$b^{46}\equiv 1\mod 47$$

$$\ a\ne 0 \mod 43{,}\quad b\ne 0 \mod 47$$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282976/solving-unknown-exponent-in-27k-≡-2-mod-2021)

Comment: What does solving the problem for each prime (43, 47) mean?

Comment: $27^9\equiv2\pmod{43}$ and $27^{21}\equiv 2\pmod{47}$

Comment: Solve $43x+47y=1$ using the particular solution $(x,y)=(-12,11)$

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that $2^{11}\equiv 27 \pmod{2021}$, suppose that $27^k\equiv 2 \pmod{2021}$.  Then $(2^{11})^k\equiv 2^{11k}\equiv 2\equiv 2^{1+j\phi(2021)} \pmod{2021}$.  Can you find $k$ and $j$ with $11k=1+j\phi(2021)$?